# Populating and deleting items from a database table by looping through checkedlistbox

Tags: c#, sql, loops, checkedlistbox

What I am trying to do is populate a second checkedlistbox based on the selected items in the first checkedlistbox, and remove the items from the database when the parent is unchecked in the first box. I am able to populate the second box by looping through only the *checked* items, however, I need to include the unchecked items as well if I am to delete them from the table. Here is the code I have at the moment:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < ckbObjectives.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            objectiveTableAdapter.ClearBeforeFill = false;

            if (ckbObjectives.GetItemChecked(i))
            {
                this.objectiveTableAdapter.FillByParentObjective((CWSToolkitDataSet.ObjectiveDataTable)cWSToolkitDataSet.Tables["ChildObjectives"], Convert.ToInt32(((DataRowView)ckbObjectives.Items[i])[ckbObjectives.ValueMember].ToString()));
            }
            else
            {
                this.objectiveTableAdapter.Delete((CWSToolkitDataSet.ObjectiveDataTable)cWSToolkitDataSet.Tables["ChildObjectives"], Convert.ToInt32(((DataRowView)ckbObjectives.Items[i])[ckbObjectives.ValueMember].ToString()));
            }
        }

        cblSubObjectives.DataSource = cWSToolkitDataSet.Tables["ChildObjectives"];
        cblSubObjectives.DisplayMember = "Title";
        cblSubObjectives.ValueMember = "ObjectiveID";
```

I am not getting any errors, however the second checkedlistbox isn't getting populated. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Have you stepped through the code? Is your code reaching `FillByParentObjective`? Is this WPF, Silverlight, Winforms, Webforms?

Comment: It's Visual Studio 2010. No, my if statement to check for checked items is returning false regardless of the item being checked. Edit: I've also tried `if (ckbObjectives.GetItemCheckState(i) == CheckState.Checked)` which is also returning false when an item is checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're checking the right things, this should be working.

Can you double check which CheckedListBox you're looping through, and ensure you're getting the right responses:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ckbObjectives.Items.Count; i++)
{
    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0}: {1}", 
                    ckbObjectives.GetItemText(ckbObjectives.Items[i]),
                    ckbObjectives.GetItemCheckState(i).ToString())); 
}
```

I'm still not sure if you're on WinForms/WebForms/WPF etc, but replace the `MessageBox.Show` above with whatever is best to output. This will at least assure you you're looking at the right, current, data.

Answer (score 0):

After setting DataSource property, usually you need to call DataBind() on the CheckedListBox in order to show the data in it. Does it help?

Comment: No, the issue is actually in my if statement logic. If I only loop through the checked items, I am able to add them using a very similar variation of the code you see above.